# How to calculate Proper Distance as an arc length in Schwarzschild metric?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, distance

I am trying to determine the method to calculate proper distance with constant time and radius in Schwarzschild Geometry. With only $\theta$ and $\phi$ being variable. I think it involves integrating the line element (metric) using two variables but an example of this is hard to find.  If I can find the integral; I can probably look up a solution in a table or use Maple?

Answer (score 1):

For a fixed $r$ and $t$,
$$ds^2 = r^2(d\theta^2 +\sin^2\theta\ d\phi^2)\ ,$$
which is the same arc length as in Euclidean space.
Then if $\phi = f(\theta)$ then
$$s =r \int \left(1 + \sin^2\theta\  \left(\frac{df}{d\theta}\right)^2\right)^{1/2}\ d\theta\ .$$

Comment: could  (df/dtheta) be related to a geometric projection? I can see that it would be useful to reduce the # of variables (phi) for integration purposes. Can the line element be integrated  including theta and phi?